# How to apply other than trivial dimensions?

Tags: complex-analysis, dimension-theory-analysis

I only used natural dimensions so far but I understand there could be

- Negative dimension with application e.g. dimension -2 definition and usage
- Non-integer dimension with application e.g. dimension ½ defintion and usage
- Imaginary dimension with application e.g. dimension 2i definition and usage

Could you please examplify why such dimension(s) like above should exist, when mathematically I suppose one could argue than one or more of the above mentioned are a consequence from definitions of what a dimension is. In complex analys something called the Riemann sphere is discussed which introduces a 4th axis, is that axis also "trivial" ?

Comment: I can't speak for negative or imaginary dimensions, but non-integer dimensions arise fairly often, for example, in fractal geometry for [Koch's snowflake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koch_snowflake) or the Hausdorff dimension of the [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

Comment: Please define "natural dimension" as a Google search doesn't turn up much that seems valuable.  [Hausdorff dimension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_dimension) might be some of what you are looking for.

Comment: In physics, relativity theory defines a relationship between space an time, in the sense that space and time can be interchanged if two observers move relative to each other. The equations for this relationship resemble those of metric spaces. The equations look as if time behaves like an "imaginary" (because in involves imaginary numbers) extra spatial dimension. Mathematically it is called  Minkowsky space, although it doesn't behave like an actual spatial four dimensional spatial space. Because of this some  people consider time as the fourth dimension, but it is not a good analogy.

Comment: @RossMillikan I think he means $R^n$

Comment: @julianfernandez: I suspect the question is not that well thought out.  If you have something that is defined as a positive integer it is natural to wonder about what happens in a larger range of numbers.  Sounds to me this is where it comes from.

Comment: @Nick the non-N dimensions usually come from an extension of the definition of distance, that is useful to use in these new systems because you can use other known math properties of metric spaces, and reduce to it for a limit case, and end up resulting in a change in the definition of dimension, which no longer belongs to N. But in my view they are math tricks, or generalizations, pretty difficult to imagine for a standard Euclidean space